# Failure creating threads with pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc

I'm compiling my code with `gcc test.c -o test.o -lpthread -lrt` when I run `test.o` nothing prints to the console. I've read the man pages and I think that my code should successfully create a new thread. Would there be any reason that the created thread isn't able print to the console?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void* thd ();

pthread_t tid;

int main()
{
  int i;

  i = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &thd, NULL);
}

void* thd ()
{
  printf("hello");
}
```

Comment: 1) `void* thd ();` is an invalid prototype. Use `void *thd(void);` 2) For the definition such declarators are deprecated. Use prototype-style here, too.

Comment: Don't forget to print a newline.  It might be an idea to wait for the threads to complete...

Comment: `pthread_join` needs to be called from `main` to wait for the thread to exit. Otherwise the main thread can exit causing all child threads to be killed before the child thread has finished (or even started).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wont print because you will end before the print (without join, you wont wait for the thread to end)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void* thd(void *);

pthread_t tid;

int main()
{
  int i;

  i = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &thd, NULL);
  pthread_join(tid, NULL);
  return 0;
}

void* thd(void *unused)
{
  printf("hello\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program creates a thread and then terminates, never giving the thread a chance to accomplish any useful work. There's no reason it should be expected to print anything.

Comment: So I should wait on the thread to exit. I see that I could use `pthread_join` to do this, is that what this is intended to be used for?

Comment: @MaxwellPowell Only because this is the termination of the process, that's a reasonable way to do it. A process should not terminate until it finishes cleaning up all the threads it created. It's commonly abused to wait until work is done, and that's (at least IMO) a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Just like David Schwartz said, the main thread need to wait for the child thread to finish. Use pthread_join inside main() to do that, like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>

void *thd(void *);

pthread_t tid;

int main()
{
  int i;

  i = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &thd, NULL);
  pthread_join(tid, NULL);
  return 0;
}

void *thd(void *unused)
{
  printf("hello\n");
  return 0;
}
```